WiX installer starts service before custom action
I have WiX installer which creates a windows service and starts it. I need to complete a few custom actions before the service starts, as they include reading some configuration files. Here is what i have defined in my install sequence :
<InstallExecuteSequence>

    <Custom Action="test" Before="StartServices">NOT Installed </Custom>

</InstallExecuteSequence>

The code that handles the install and start/stop of the service is  :
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                                Type="ownProcess"
                                Vital="yes"
                                Name="MyWindowsService"
                                DisplayName="MyWindowsService"
                                Description="New Windows Service"
                                Start="auto"
                                Account="LocalSystem"
                                ErrorControl="normal" />
                
                <ServiceControl Id="StartService"
                                Name="MyWindowsService"
                                Start="install"
                                Stop="both"
                                Remove="uninstall"
                                Wait="yes" />

                
                <ServiceControl Id="StopService"
                                Name="MyWindowsService"
                                Stop="uninstall"
                                Remove="uninstall"
                                Wait="yes" />

Despite this, my service starts before the custom action is completed and, i receive an error for not loading the config files.
Is there a different way to ensure the custom action completes before starting my services?
